# CSS Layout Disparity (using Twitter Bootstrap on Octopress)

Tags: css, heroku, twitter-bootstrap, octopress

Background: I'm currently bringing my Tumblr blog, with a (lightly) customised Bootstrap theme, over to Octopress.

Tumblr site: http://eatsleeprepeat.net/
Octopress site (WIP): http://stark-autumn-3851.herokuapp.com/
Github: https://github.com/elithrar/octopress/tree/master/.themes/eatsleeprepeat (see sass/ for the stylesheets)

The biggest problem right now is the way the `hero-unit` that contains the individual posts is not conforming (from what I can see) to the `@media` statements in the _bootstrap_responsive.css file, which is loaded at the bottom of `screen.css` on the site itself (via Octopress).

The HTML structure is identical (as far as the hero-unit div is concerned), and Web Inspector in Chrome isn't telling me anything useful (read: that I can understand).

If there's someone with some good CSS-fu and a few minutes to spare, I'd very much appreciate it.

**Update**: I've resolved the issue with the hero-unit (horizontally), so it now respects the page size. It was due to a *really* obvious error: "id" instead of "class" for container.

However, saying that: I still have an issue with the vertical alignment of the `hero-unit` underneath the `navbar navbar-fixed-top` div; there's no spacing between them.

Comment: where is that hero unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by adding the following:

```
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add these CSS rules:

```
.container::before, .container::after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
.container::after {
    clear: both;
}
.container::before, .container::after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: No such luck unfortunately—appended it to the end of the existing CSS and no difference.